# Change SVG Fill and text highlight color on hover

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

I have a Nav menu item with an SVG image. Currently if I hover over the SVG it changes to red and my text highlights to white. However, when I hover over the text it highlights to white, but the SVG doesn't change to red. When I hover over either the SVG or the text, I'd like both to change. I was trying this but it's not working.

```css
.nav-icon {
  fill: white;
}

.nav-icon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nav-icon text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-100 flex items-center py-2 px-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md group border-l-4 border-transparent">
  <svg width="20" height="20" class="nav-icon flex-none mr-3 text-gray-400 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true">
   <path d="M2.3999 6.0001C2.3999 4.67461 3.47442 3.6001 4.7999 3.6001H13.1999C14.5254 3.6001 15.5999 4.67461 15.5999 6.0001V10.8001C15.5999 12.1256 14.5254 13.2001 13.1999 13.2001H10.7999L7.1999 16.8001V13.2001H4.7999C3.47442 13.2001 2.3999 12.1256 2.3999 10.8001V6.0001Z"/>
   <path d="M17.9999 8.4001V11.6001C17.9999 13.8092 16.209 15.6001 13.9999 15.6001H11.794L9.67397 17.7201C10.0097 17.8988 10.393 18.0001 10.7999 18.0001H13.1999L16.7999 21.6001V18.0001H19.1999C20.5254 18.0001 21.5999 16.9256 21.5999 15.6001V10.8001C21.5999 9.47461 20.5254 8.4001 19.1999 8.4001H17.9999Z"/>
   </svg>
   Message
 </a>
```

Comment: You say that the text changes to white on hover, that must be done elsewhere because there's nothing in your given code that changes color. Can you put up a working snippet (which, I guess, needs to include relevant part of tailwind?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish from the provided code. But here's a few circumstances you may be interested in accomplishing with Tailwind, and the additional CSS is really not needed.

#### Situation 1 - Same color icon and text color change on hover

This is the most common circumstance, the user hovers the element and the icon and text change together. To do this you only need the class `fill-current` on the SVG and `hover:text-{your-color}` on the parent element (anchor tag in your case). Here's a Tailwind Play example of that https://play.tailwindcss.com/Zy2tdj05Tf

A simple example of that would look like this:

```
<a href="#" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-white">
  <svg class="fill-current"> <!-- some svg code --> </svg>
</a>
```

The full code from the Tailwind play is:

```
<a href="#" class="bg-blue-900 text-gray-400 hover:text-white flex items-center py-2 px-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md group border-l-4 border-transparent">
   <svg width="20" height="20" class="flex-none mr-3 fill-current" aria-hidden="true">
     <path d="M2.3999 6.0001C2.3999 4.67461 3.47442 3.6001 4.7999 3.6001H13.1999C14.5254 3.6001 15.5999 4.67461 15.5999 6.0001V10.8001C15.5999 12.1256 14.5254 13.2001 13.1999 13.2001H10.7999L7.1999 16.8001V13.2001H4.7999C3.47442 13.2001 2.3999 12.1256 2.3999 10.8001V6.0001Z"/>
     <path d="M17.9999 8.4001V11.6001C17.9999 13.8092 16.209 15.6001 13.9999 15.6001H11.794L9.67397 17.7201C10.0097 17.8988 10.393 18.0001 10.7999 18.0001H13.1999L16.7999 21.6001V18.0001H19.1999C20.5254 18.0001 21.5999 16.9256 21.5999 15.6001V10.8001C21.5999 9.47461 20.5254 8.4001 19.1999 8.4001H17.9999Z"/>
   </svg>
   Message
</a>
```

#### Situation 2 - Different icon and text color on hover

Less common, the user hovers and the icon and text both change but to different colors from each other. It's a similar setup but you will need to make the parent element a group and use `group-hover` to change the text color independently on the SVG. And here's a Tailwind Play of that https://play.tailwindcss.com/Jsx4bOtQwx

The most simple version of this is:

```
<a href="#" class="text-gray-400 hover:text-white group">
  <svg class="group-hover:text-red fill-current"> <!-- some svg code --> </svg>
</a>
```

And the full code from the Play example is:

```
<a href="#" class="bg-blue-900 text-gray-400 group hover:text-green-600 flex items-center py-2 px-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md group border-l-4 border-transparent">
    <svg width="20" height="20" class="flex-none group-hover:text-red-600 mr-3 fill-current" aria-hidden="true">
      <path d="M2.3999 6.0001C2.3999 4.67461 3.47442 3.6001 4.7999 3.6001H13.1999C14.5254 3.6001 15.5999 4.67461 15.5999 6.0001V10.8001C15.5999 12.1256 14.5254 13.2001 13.1999 13.2001H10.7999L7.1999 16.8001V13.2001H4.7999C3.47442 13.2001 2.3999 12.1256 2.3999 10.8001V6.0001Z"/>
      <path d="M17.9999 8.4001V11.6001C17.9999 13.8092 16.209 15.6001 13.9999 15.6001H11.794L9.67397 17.7201C10.0097 17.8988 10.393 18.0001 10.7999 18.0001H13.1999L16.7999 21.6001V18.0001H19.1999C20.5254 18.0001 21.5999 16.9256 21.5999 15.6001V10.8001C21.5999 9.47461 20.5254 8.4001 19.1999 8.4001H17.9999Z"/>
    </svg>
    Message
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the same class for both blocks. And when hovering, the property changes for the element that received the hover. That is, when you hover the mouse over the text, the `fill` property  changes for the text, not for the SVG.

For your task you should use the `.nav-icon` class for the parent `<a>` element only. And change on `:hover` CSS properties for both elements:

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.nav-icon {
  color: red;
}

.nav-icon svg {
  fill: white;
}

.nav-icon:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav-icon:hover svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="nav-icon text-gray-300 hover:text-gray-100 flex items-center py-2 px-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md group border-l-4 border-transparent">
  <svg width="20" height="20" class="flex-none mr-3 text-gray-400 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true">
   <path d="M2.3999 6.0001C2.3999 4.67461 3.47442 3.6001 4.7999 3.6001H13.1999C14.5254 3.6001 15.5999 4.67461 15.5999 6.0001V10.8001C15.5999 12.1256 14.5254 13.2001 13.1999 13.2001H10.7999L7.1999 16.8001V13.2001H4.7999C3.47442 13.2001 2.3999 12.1256 2.3999 10.8001V6.0001Z"/>
   <path d="M17.9999 8.4001V11.6001C17.9999 13.8092 16.209 15.6001 13.9999 15.6001H11.794L9.67397 17.7201C10.0097 17.8988 10.393 18.0001 10.7999 18.0001H13.1999L16.7999 21.6001V18.0001H19.1999C20.5254 18.0001 21.5999 16.9256 21.5999 15.6001V10.8001C21.5999 9.47461 20.5254 8.4001 19.1999 8.4001H17.9999Z"/>
   </svg>
   Message
</a>
```

Comment: There's no need to use regular CSS for any of this, it can all be done with Tailwind.

Comment: @JHeth the opposite is also true :) But the main thing is that I corrected what the author of the question posted. The author is currently using the CSS.

Comment: Indeed, the author could avoid using Tailwind altogether and switch their project to being vanilla CSS. However, if they're using Tailwind they should probably only utilize vanilla CSS when absolutely necessary.

Comment: @JHeth I myself would be interested and useful to see the solution to this task in pure Tailwind.

Comment: Added an answer with some examples on Tailwind Play, Tailwind makes SVG styling simple and the `group` utilities make complex, nested hover styling possible :)